# Pass runtime variables into bash script which does ssh to remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to ssh into remote servers and run a few commands at some particular time. I noticed that once the ssh is established using arg1 ($1), the arg2($2) is no longer valid. Unfortunately I cant install any tool within my linux server, so is there any other way of doing this?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Host = ' $1
USERNAME=ec2-user
KEY=/home/xxx/xxx.pem
ssh -l ${USERNAME} -i ${KEY} $1 '
  while true
  do
    echo $(date)
    echo stats | nc localhost 11211 | grep cmd_flush
    if [$2 == 'sec']; then
      sleep 1
    elif [$2 == 'min']; then
      sleep 1m
    elif [$2 == '30min']; then
      sleep 30m
    elif [$2 == 'hr']; then
      sleep 1h
    elif [$2 == '12hr']; then
      sleep 12h
    elif [$2 == 'day']; then
      sleep 1d
    elif [$2 == 'week']; then
      sleep 7d
    else
      echo "None of the condition met"
    fi
  done
' | tee /var/log/$1_$2.log
```

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net to fix some common mistakes.

Comment: It is not about $2 or ssh, is about the simple quotes you are using. Using `'` prevents variable expansion.

Comment: @Miguel That single quotes is because I want to reuse the same ssh connection and need to keep it alive. If I hard code the values, the script runs fine. But I dont want to create many codes for diff time. frames.

Comment: Right now you are sending sleep commands to the destination server.  You could instead setup cron jobs on your source server.  And the cron jobs would call the ssh commands only once on your destination servers.  Move the timing logic from the destination, to the source.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute a command at a specific time, evaluate this on the source pc, you can troubleshoot quicker and more easily, plus you can install tools on your source pc. You only need to connect to the remote pc to run a command only, not to leave a connection open to run the `sleep` command. sleep can be run on your source pc instead.